# I would like to modularize Backbone.js views so that Javascript and Templates are located in the same file

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

If I have only one file to include I could include it into the website and in the testing page, however I can't do that because template is located on the same page where it is used.

Comment: this is a very broad question, lets start with some rebound questions: 1) what templates? what templating engine? underscore? jquery-templates? other?  2) how are you including them, are you using some sort of javascript loader? or placing the files in your markup yourself? ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use some kind of module loader (AMD or CommonJS) to handle that. We are using [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) using the text plugin to load text (any type of file in raw form template.tpl etc.) will work. And then just make your template a dependency for any module that can require it.

Also if your template engine of choice requires or supports precompiled templates you can create your own plugin for [requirejs](http://requirejs.org/) to compile the templates for you on the fly as they are required so you don't have to do that manually.

Here is an [example tutorial](http://backbonetutorials.com/organizing-backbone-using-modules/) how to use it with Backbone

Embrace AMD/CommonJS and enjoy it!

Comment: Or don't since AMD support was pulled from Underscore and, honestly, we want to reduce the number of external calls since each one increases latency.  We have a single "page" application -- templates are in the .html file, which also includes the CSS and Javascript (all compressed).  On the dev end, it's a slew of CSS and JS files all separated out and separate templates.  We have a Python script that "compiles" the page and runs unit tests when we deploy to the live server.

Comment: W are using AMD and hey! Our deploy also uses build and testing step before sending files to the server - it packs the AMD modules together into one (or few files fetched on demand when certain app module needs to be loaded to reduce initial load time and make updating part of the platform not have to force clear cache of all JS). Using AMD doesn't stop you from packing all the JS to one file, I'd dare to say it makes it filthy easy - don't think you've used AMD to its full extent if you have had a chance to use it. AMD was removed from underscore for other reasons - not because AMD is bad.

Comment: if you really wanted you could even pack all the JS, CSS, templates and images into one file - all using AMD